# How to make the setting fancyhdr for \frontmatter is same as for \mainmatter?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, books, front-matter

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hfil
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[OL]{%
        \Chaptername
    }    
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[ER]{%
        \rightmark{ 
            \footnotesize\textbf{INTRODUCTION TO MATLAB}
        }
    }
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{PREFACE}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \lipsum[1-8]
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

I have a problem in making footer. In `\mainmatter` is no problem. In `\frontmatter` there is a problem.

I want the even page the footer is book title (with page number) and the odd page is chapter name (with page number). The result in `\mainmatter` is no problem. But in `\frontmatter`, if I make chapter preface, the footer of TOC (in odd page) is "PREFACE". Also, in even page, "CONTENTS" appear with book title. (see my picture above)

Why the setting `fancyhdr` is not in accordance with setting as for `\mainmatter`?

How to make the setting `fancyhdr` for `\frontmatter` is same as for `\mainmatter`?

**ADDENDUM:**

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,papersize={15.5cm,23.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum,xcolor,hyperref}
\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    %\renewcommand*\footrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hfil
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[OL]{%
        \footnotesize\textbf{\nouppercase{\Chaptername}}%
    }    
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[ER]{%
        \footnotesize\textbf{INTRODUCTION TO MATLAB}%
    }
}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}[mystyle]{
    \fancyfoot[OL]{%
        \footnotesize\textbf{\nouppercase{\Chaptername}}%
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \pagestyle{frontmatter}
    \chapter{PREFACE}
    \lipsum[1-20]
    {%
        \cleardoublepage
        \newpage
        \renewcommand{\Chaptername}{CONTENTS}
        \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
        \tableofcontents
    }%
    \mainmatter
    \pagestyle{mystyle}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \lipsum[1-8]
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
\end{document}
```

I have tried Pieter van Oostrum's answer and there is little modification from me.

But, the result in footer of contents is "PREFACE".

[image]

Comment: Note: Code markup with backticks does not work in titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `\rightmark` from the footer.That didn't make sense anyway, I think.

```
    \fancyfoot[ER]{%
            \footnotesize\textbf{INTRODUCTION TO MATLAB}%
    }
```

2. You use `\Chaptername` in the left footer, so you have to set that.

```
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{PREFACE}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \newpage
    \renewcommand{\Chaptername}{CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
```

Now, if you also are going to use the "capitalise words" trick in the footer, like in one of your previous questions, this will be changed to "Contents" instead of "CONTENTS". If you don't want that then you would need a `\fancyfoot[OL]` without the `\mycapswords`. The safest way to do that is to define a pagestyle `front matter` for that.

Here is a complete example. **NOTE**: The `\fancypagestyle` with the optional argument needs `fancyhdr` version 4.

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\mycapswords[1]{\ecapitalisewords{\text_lowercase:n {#1}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\let\Chaptermark\chaptermark
\def\chaptermark#1{\def\Chaptername{#1}\Chaptermark{#1}}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[OR]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hfil
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[OL]{%
        \mycapswords{\Chaptername}%
    }    
    \fancyfoot[EL]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[ER]{%
            \footnotesize\textbf{INTRODUCTION TO MATLAB}%
    }
}
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}[mystyle]{
    \fancyfoot[OL]{%
        \Chaptername
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \pagestyle{frontmatter}
    \chapter{PREFACE}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \newpage
    \renewcommand{\Chaptername}{CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \pagestyle{mystyle}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \lipsum[1-8]
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, with a modification, but in footer of TOC is displaying PREFACE. See my edited question.

Comment: I tried to remove "{" and "}"
`{%
        \cleardoublepage
        \newpage
        \renewcommand{\Chaptername}{CONTENTS}
        \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
        \tableofcontents
    }%`

and it's work.

Comment: Using `\fancyfoot[OL]{\leftmark}` in the frontmatter pagestyle should also work. Then there is no need for defining `\Chaptername` or using `\phantomsection`.

Answer (score 1):

With a few changes to your code for `mystyle`, it is possible to achieve the goal of having the `frontmatter` headings the same as the `mainmatter`.

The rest of the document does not need any changes.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor,lipsum}

\colorlet{myfancycolor}{black}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{% 
    \fancyhf{} % added 
    \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{##1}{} }% % added <<<<
    \renewcommand*\footrulewidth{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hfil
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[LO]{ \leftmark}  % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  
    \fancyfoot[LE]{%
        \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
        \color{myfancycolor}
        \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
        \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
            \hbox to2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}%
    }
    \fancyfoot[RE]{%
            \footnotesize\textbf{INTRODUCTION TO MATLAB}
    }
}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{PREFACE}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \lipsum[1-8]
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
    \chapter{LALALA LALALA LALALA}
\end{document}
```

If you do not want the double rule use  `\renewcommand*\footrulewidth{0pt}`

To unify the `plain` style --used on the first page of the chapters-- with `mystyle`, you can add

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
        \fancyhf{}
        \renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
        \fancyfoot[C]{%
            \kern-3ex % all material is shifted up by 3ex
            \color{myfancycolor}
            \hrule height1pt % your \hrule
            \hfill  \hbox{\rlap{\vrule height1.3em width2em depth.7em}% you black box
                \hbox to 2em{\hss\color{white}{\textsf{\thepage}}\hss}}\hfill%
        }
}
```

[image: c]